# How to select first matching row from the CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

From a simple table in SQL Server with two columns like below

```
Key   Value
------------
A     5000
B     NULL
C     6000
```

I want to get the first record in the order `B,A,C` (i.e. get value of B and if null then value of A, and if null, value of C ) where `Value` is not null. From the above list I expect the output to be `5000`

I'm trying with this code - without any luck:

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN [Key] = 'B' AND Value IS NOT NULL
          THEN Value
       WHEN [Key] = 'A' AND Value IS NOT NULL 
          THEN Value
       WHEN [Key] = 'C' AND Value IS NOT NULL
          THEN Value
    END
FROM
    temporary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . one method uses `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(max(case when [Key] = 'B' then value end),
                max(case when [Key] = 'A' then value end),
                max(case when [Key] = 'C' then value end)
               )
from temporary;
```

But, I think I would do:

```
select top 1 t.value
from temporary t
where value is not null and [Key] in ('A', 'B', 'C')
order by charindex([Key], 'B,A,C');
```

Note that the `order by` is just a shorthand for getting the preferred ordering.  It works for "A", "B", and "C", but might not generalize to all strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `where` clause to omit `null` `value`s, order by your custom sorting (using a `case` expression) and just take the `top 1` row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 value
FROM   mytable
WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CASE key WHEN 'B' THEN 0
                  WHEN 'A' THEN 1
                  WHEN 'C' THEN 2
                  ELSE 3
         END ASC
```